# Windows 8 Tile App and get data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a new Windows 8 Tile App to display the contents of the database table.
I am following WCF service approach for my app to talk to SQL Server.
I did a lot of researches and found few good articles and following this one:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/insert-update-and-delete-data-in-gridview-using-wcf-service/

So based on the article, I have created a WCF service and a web application to access the service.
WCF service returns the DataSet which I am getting into a variable like this (in MainPage.xaml.cs on the web application side):

```
var reviewList = await objServiceClientobjService.GetInWorkReviewAsync();
```

The 'reviewList' variable gets a whole string of database contents means into a serialized form but I would like it as deserialized form or into a list to display into rows.

I have been trying to follow the code lines below but none works and System.Data is not supported in Windows 8 and I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8.

```
IEnumerable sequence = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

OR

```
List list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

OR

```
List newList = new List();
```

Do I need to make any changes to web.config?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own model witch you can use to get data from SQL and even to use the data in your Windows 8 App.

To be able to share that model you need to use the so called `Portable Class Library` witch is a type of Project that can be referenced from multiple platforms as Windows Phone, Windows 8, .NET 4+, Silverlight and few others, depends on your needs.

Using WCF, when adding the Service Reference, SVCUtil should automatically create a type for you to use.
As in the example you are following you have the `UserDetails` class.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have added my own SQL server details and have done it all which you mentioned. It all works. Its just at the end I am getting data into serialised form while I need it into rows format.

Comment: You should have UserDetails available in your Windows 8 App

Comment: And when you call GetUsers what do you receive? a string?

Comment: yes a string form like this: "112345InWorkReviewABC-ABC-ABC-ABCDarrenSmithDarren Smith2013-08-20T14:52:30.54+01:002013-08-20T14:52:30.54+01:000.50Testtrue2013-08-20T14:52:30.54+......"

Comment: please post some WCF methods and Reference.cs from your Windows 8 Application